# bakers chocolate vs chocolate chips

Tags: chocolate

My husband is on a dairy free, low sugar diet. How do I create a substitute for chocolate chips. The store bought sugar free chips usually are seasonal and have dairy in them.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Peggy. Sugar and dairy free chocolate chips should be available online. If you would like a recipe then this question is off-topic I'm afraid.

Comment: ...could maybe try cocoa nibs, they're sometimes available.  Texture will be a bit different, but might work